# kendo ui mobile scheduler - Event Scrolling Issue on iOS (iPhone and iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scheduler, kendo-mobile

We have an issue that seems to only affect the iOS platform (iPhone and iPad).  Below is some sample code that displays the same issue and the link for this is below:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/m/index#scheduler/adaptive

The issue is that you cannot scroll down the screen if you try to scroll while your finger is on an event.  For example if I put my finger on any of the events and move my finger up or down then the view isn't scrollable.  If you put your finger on a white space i.e. a space on the scheduler that does not have any events then you are allowed to scroll up and down.  Android does not have this issue at all.

Has anyone else had this issue and are there any fixes please?